# PHP regular expression - preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I would like to delete, in this two strings, the part in square brackets. In this example I would like to print the two string without "[No Change]" and "[New]".

```
<?php

$str_1 = "[No Change]  Busta Rhymes ft. Kanye West, Lil Wayne & Q-Tip - Thank You";
$str_2 = "[New] B.o.B ft. Chris Brown - Throwback";

$str_1 = preg_replace("/\[[^A-Z0-9a-z\w ]\]/", "", $str_1);
$str_2 = preg_replace("/\[[^A-Z0-9a-z\w ]\]/", "", $str_2);

echo $str_1; // Result: [No Change]  Busta Rhymes ft. Kanye West, Lil Wayne & Q-Tip - Thank You
echo $str_2; // Result: [New] B.o.B ft. Chris Brown - Throwback
?>
```

I write this PHP code but seems not to work.

Comment: Try doing it with preg_replace("/\[[^]]+\]/", "", $str_1);

Comment: @ShekharChikara: the best answer here. or the same with `*` in place of `+`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$str_1 = preg_replace("/\[[A-Z0-9a-z\w ]+\]/", "", $str_1);
$str_2 = preg_replace("/\[[A-Z0-9a-z\w ]+\]/", "", $str_2);
```

[DEMO](https://eval.in/84638)

If you want to discard anything that is in between third bracket your regex is actually simpler.
That will be `\[.+\]`

Comment: Hi chanchal118!
Fantastic, it work!
Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Try the following regex pattern:

```
/\[[^\]]*\]?/g
```

Answer (score 1):

There is working regexp code

```
$str_1 = preg_replace('/\[[^\]]*\]/', "", $str_1);
$str_2 = preg_replace('/\[[^\]]*\]/', "", $str_2);
```

And don't use double quote for regexp then you need escape char '\' too